# Filtering data.frame so there is only one unique value per group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

If the '`value`' is equal (or the same) from `day1` till `day7` in `dplyr` how can I add up the `n` column? Also, how can I `filter` to have only `n` that are equal with `7`

Preferable output:

[image]

Data sample:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), timeslot = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), value = c(110, 110, 110, 
110, 110, 110, 110, 9990, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 9990, 110, 
110, 110, 110, 8310, 110), n = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), groups = structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), timeslot = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), value = c(110, 
110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 9990, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 
9990, 110, 110, 110, 110, 8310, 110), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dat %>% 
     group_by(id) %>%
     ## test whether there is only one unique value per ID
     filter(length(unique(value)) == 1) %>% 
     ## sum up n 
     mutate(n = sum(n)) %>% 
     filter(n==7)
```

```
# A tibble: 7 × 5
# Groups:   id [1]
     id   day timeslot value     n
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1        1   110     7
2     1     2        1   110     7
3     1     3        1   110     7
4     1     4        1   110     7
5     1     5        1   110     7
6     1     6        1   110     7
7     1     7        1   110     7
```

Comment: You can do both in one `filter`: `dat %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(sum(n) == 7, length(unique(value)) == 1)`

Answer (score 1):

I'll sneak in a little data.table approach because that's always popular - it is counting the number of observations and number of unique values (per id for both of those), then generating a data.table with id and the logical conditions evaluated, which is then merged onto the original data, which is finally filtered.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
data1[data1[, .(.N, uniqueN(value)), by=id][, .(id, N==7 & V2==1)], on="id"][V2==TRUE, -c("V2")]
```

---

Edit: Credit to IceCreamToucan for the main work in this solution - I just wanted to add a bit of detail around it and make some slight tweaks. This puts an `if` statement into the `j` of `DT[i, j, by]` (see[(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) for details). When that `if` statement resolves to `TRUE`, it is returning the selected variables given by the special character, `.SD` — `.SDcols` was missing so it defaulted to all columns. This version also uses the `.N`  special character — a synonym for `nrows()`. This `j`-process is done `by` id.

```
data1[, if(.N==7 & uniqueN(value)==1){.SD}, by=id]
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, if (sum(n) == 7 && uniqueN(value) == 1) .SD, by = id]
#>    id day timeslot value n
#> 1:  1   1        1   110 1
#> 2:  1   2        1   110 1
#> 3:  1   3        1   110 1
#> 4:  1   4        1   110 1
#> 5:  1   5        1   110 1
#> 6:  1   6        1   110 1
#> 7:  1   7        1   110 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Let's name your dataframe as df.

So you can use this:

```
# Add up column "n"
df %>% 
  left_join(df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(total_n = sum(n)) ) %>% 
  select(everything(), - n) %>% 
  filter(total_n == 7)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   id, day, timeslot, value [20]
      id   day timeslot value total_n
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
 1     1     1        1   110       7
 2     1     2        1   110       7
 3     1     3        1   110       7
 4     1     4        1   110       7
 5     1     5        1   110       7
 6     1     6        1   110       7
 7     1     7        1   110       7
 8     2     1        2  9990       7
 9     2     2        2   110       7
10     2     3        2   110       7
11     2     4        2   110       7
12     2     5        2   110       7
13     2     6        2   110       7
14     2     7        2  9990       7
```

Answer (score 0):

Update after clarification (thanks to rg255):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(n=ifelse(n_distinct(value)==1, n(), 0)) %>% 
  filter(n == 7)
```

```
     id   day timeslot value     n
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1        1   110     7
2     1     2        1   110     7
3     1     3        1   110     7
4     1     4        1   110     7
5     1     5        1   110     7
6     1     6        1   110     7
7     1     7        1   110     7
```

Comment: @rg255 Thank you for pointing there. Please see my update.